# Should I be using Vue Mixins, "extends" or Vuex to share a method across all my components?

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, vuex, mixins

I want to have a Vue method that can be imported and used by any one of my Vue components. This method's job will be to handle exceptions passed to it (shown below).

```
handleException(err) {
   console.error(err);
   // send exception to error logging service
   // do some other error-related stuff.
}
```

As far as I know, there are three main ways to accomplish this (please enlighten me if there are more ways that I am not aware of):

1. Have the method within a [Vue Mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Basics) and import this into any components that need the  method.
2. Create a component containing the handleException method and use the "extends" keyword to import the template. ([Pretty similar approach to Mixins approach](https://medium.com/js-dojo/extending-vuejs-components-42fefefc688b)).
3. Have the method in Vuex (as an action), which will allow me to call the method from any component using this.$store.dispatch...

**For my use case, what is the best approach and why?**

Comment: if you want to import it, then mixin, if you just want to have global access to it... then mixin or vuex.

Comment: I would have a vuex state for the exceptions service. For me it will be easier that way because makes it possible so for multiple components to listen on that state. With that you can also let other vuex states listen/watch the exception state. One other bonus is, that the component is a bit cleaner with this separation.